# Delete or Change resource files from apk

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, apktool

is there any way to delete or change resource files (in my case some mp3 files) in an apk file?

I have an App installed, which has a horrible alarm sound, which i can not turn off.
I tried to decompile with apktool, but i can not recompile, when i changed the ressources.

Is it even possible? And if yes, how?

This is the error from recompiling with apktool btw:

```
W: invalid resource directory name: D:\Benutzer\Downloads\libre3\res navigation
brut.androlib.exceptions.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): 
[C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_84578783194560097958652494267055047653.tmp, p, 
--forced-package-id, 127, 
--min-sdk-version, 26, 
--target-sdk-version, 30, 
--version-code, 9593, 
--version-name, 3.4.2, 
--no-version-vectors, 
-F, C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL17865495575416047266.tmp, 
-e, C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL13346287661765600551.tmp, 
-0, arsc, 
-I, C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk,
-S, D:\Benutzer\Downloads\libre3\res, 
-M, D:\Benutzer\Downloads\libre3\AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Comment: Most likely you have deleted a file that is referenced somewhere else. If you only want to change resources try to disable source decompilation using the argument `--no-src`.

Comment: I copied a "silence.mp3" and gave it the name of the .mp3-files i tried to remove or edit

Comment: For that you don't need to use `apktool`. Simply use a ZIP UI tool like 7-Zip to replace the file. Then zipalign and resign the APK file.

Comment: It kinda worked. I could install the app, but when I start it, i'll just get a white screen with the logo of the app (normally the screen is yellow) and then nothing happens.